# Getting Naxxramas cards without buying Naxxramas?

Tags: hearthstone

Is there anyway to get Naxxramas specific cards without buying Naxxramas?

Comment: You don't "buy" Naxxramas. The first wing is free, and unlocks some cards, the rest of the wings cost gold or money

Comment: @Kevin You should probably make that an answer.

Comment: @Kevin is the first wing free? Every time I check it asks be to pay 700 gold for it.

Comment: @GarrettJ The first wing was only free if you entered it prior to September 30th.  Otherwise it is the same price as the other wings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The below answer was true up until the recent introduction of "Standard". Naxxramas (and all other adventures over 2 years old) have been retired, and [their reward cards are now craftable](https://youtu.be/0KNQsYBrNtY).

Previous answer ---

"All of the cards from Curse of Naxxramas can only be obtained by defeating the encounters found within Naxxramas."

-Aratil, Blizzard Community Manager

Thread found [here](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/12504570789).